# Show custom content when loop or wp query reaches specific time?

Tags: wp-query, loop, scheduled-posts

Like Facebook, the birthday of a user will showing something like “month year day, you were born” on his timeline, or on someday it will show “graduated form ?? School”.

**Is it possible for Wordpress query or loop likely to show some custom content when date reaches special day?**

I know I can add a custom post type and set schedules, but if it comes to “birthday” or “anniversary”, cycles every year or month, custom post type way will be not so easy.

is there any other way to achieve this like showing something one time at xxxx, showing every year on xxx? Or automatic schedule a post and publish it on the customized cycled date or time?

By the way I think the solution to this will help with the advertisements showing on loop too. :)

Comment: What is your issue? You are asking three questions in one topic. Do you want to send birthday notifications to the user? Do you want to publish a post on somebody's birthday?  You need to compare the current date with a meta field with the corresponding date. Starting from the loop, you are ending up with advertisements? Please improve your question and define your goal more correctly.

Comment: @user3135691 showing “birthday” “anniversary” “advertisement”... isn’t that the same?  Time relevant, customized content. I don’t see there’re 3 questions in this.

Comment: In terms of code, it does matter. I have given you the correct hint. Compare a meta field that holds the date with the current date. That's it.

Comment: @user3135691 Thanks, but I need to show these content in main loop, so first thought came to me is creating a custom posttype and use wp schedule to run it every xx time, when that time comes creat a post an publish it, but this way will add cron jobs may delay the server, so I am asking if there is a better way. Thanks for the advice anyway.

Comment: still don't understand what you are trying to achive, sorry.